# How can i remove an object from an array state in Redux/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to remove an object from an array onClick when I click on the delete button, I write some code in my redux and react as well and it is not working !!

***My reducers***

```
import { ActionsTypes } from "../Constant/ActionsTypes";

argument(state, action)


const initialState = {
    events : [],
    days : (""),
};


export const SetEventReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
      case ActionsTypes.SET_EVENTS : 
            return {... state, events : action.payload};
      default : 
        return state;
    }

};


export const trackDaysReducer = (state= initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ActionsTypes.TRACK_DAYS: 
            return {... state, days : action.payload}
        default : 
            return state;
    }
};



export const removeEventReducer = (state = initialState,action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
      case ActionsTypes.REMOVE_EVENT : 
            return {}
      default : 
        return state;
    }

};
```

***Event array represents my state array***

***My Event Component who contains the button***

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { RemoveEvent } from '../Redux/Actions/ActionsEvents';

const Event = () => {
    const events = useSelector((state)=> state.allEvents.events);
    const removeEvents = useSelector((state)=> state.removeEvents);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const removeEventHandler = () => {
        dispatch(RemoveEvent({}))
    }
    return (
    <section>
    {events.map((singleEvent)=> {
        const {title, id, day} = singleEvent;
        return (
            <article className="event-pop-up" key={id} >
                <h1>The Name of your Event is <span>{title}</span></h1>
                <button className="btn event"
                        onClick={removeEventHandler}>
                            Delete Event</button>
            </article>
         )
    })}
    </section>
    )
}

export default Event;
```

***RemoveEventAction***

```
export const RemoveEvent = (id) => {
    return {
        type : ActionsTypes.REMOVE_EVENT,
    };
};
```

***This is the link to check out the app*** : https://boring-boyd-ecbeee.netlify.app/

What do you think? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

in yours reducers :

```
export const removeEventReducer = (state = initialState,action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
      case ActionsTypes.REMOVE_EVENT : 
            return {... state, events : state.events.filter((event) => event.id !== action.payload)} // payload = id in this case
      default : 
        return state;
    }
```

then in your  Event Component who contains the button :

```
import React from 'react'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { RemoveEvent} from '../Redux/Actions/ActionsEvents';

const Event = () => {
    const events = useSelector((state)=> state.allEvents.events);
    const removeEvents = useSelector((state)=> state.removeEvents);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const removeEventHandler = (id) => {
        dispatch(RemoveEvent(id))
    }
    return (
    <section>
    {events.map((singleEvent)=> {
        const {title, id, day} = singleEvent;
        return (
            <article className="event-pop-up" key={id} >
                <h1>The Name of your Event is <span>{title}</span></h1>
                <button className="btn event"
                        onClick={()=> removeEventHandler(id)}>
                            Delete Event</button>
            </article>
         )
    })}
    </section>
    )
}

export default Event;
```

then in your RemoveEvent  action

```
export const RemoveEvent = (id) => {
    return {
        type : ActionsTypes.REMOVE_EVENT, payload: id
    };
};
```

Comment: Should the action of removeEventReduce stay the same or should I pass a payload to it?

Comment: Yes pass the event id which you want to delete. and then in reducer use `filter` method to filter out that event from the event array. The above answer is what you need.

Comment: Yes the action's payload of removeEventReduce should equal the event's id that you want to delete

Comment: I updated my code above and i updated my action remove event and I pass id to it please check out if it is correct or not

Comment: I don't see the update, where can i check

Comment: Take a look at RemoveEventAction in my code above please

Comment: I got an error in removeEventReducer that events is not defined?

Comment: Sorry, that is my fault, try this in your ``removeEventReducer ``
``return {... state, events : state.events.filter((event) => event.id !== action.payload)}``

I edited my post.

Comment: should I change something in my dispatch function inside the Event component because i updated the code and  it still giving me id is not defined  :D

Comment: take a look again in my post, we well get it hhh 
``const removeEventHandler = (id) => {
        dispatch(RemoveEvent(id))
    }``

Comment: Thank you so much Nokwiw for your help We did It :D hahah, Just only one last thing is that when I click on the button to remove this object I would like that the pop-up will not to be displayed! do you have any idea how to do that :D

Comment: Sorry I have any idea.
basically when you delete the event from the store, the app will re-render and you don't be able to show the event anymore.
If you still have the pop-up, that means there are a problem somewhere in you app
I am just checked your store in the Redux DevTools, whene I delete the event, nothing is done at the store.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove an event using it's id.

```
const removeEventHandler = (id) => {
    dispatch(RemoveEvent(id))
}
return (
<section>
{events.map((singleEvent)=> {
    const {title, id, day} = singleEvent;
    return (
        <article className="event-pop-up" key={id} >
            <h1>The Name of your Event is <span>{title}</span></h1>
            <button className="btn event"
                    onClick={() => removeEventHandler(id)}>
                        Delete Event</button>
        </article>
     )
})}
</section>
```

After passing this `id` to the reducer you can loop through the events array and remove this event from array and set the new state.

And in your reducers, you can use `filter()` method to remove a particular event having that `id`

```
 export const removeEventReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
      case ActionsTypes.REMOVE_EVENT : 
            return {... state, events : state.events.filter((event) => event.id !== action.payload)}
      default : 
        return state;
    }
}
```

For Remove Event Action:

```
export const RemoveEvent = (id) => {
    return {
        type : ActionsTypes.REMOVE_EVENT,
        payload: id,
    };
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but Where should I pass the id in the reducer?

Comment: @TheRealJohnDoe I have added the code for reducer in the answer. id will be passed in action param of the reducer function, which we will use in filter() method to remove that event.

Comment: I updated my code above and I updated my action remove event and I pass id to it please check out if it is correct or not

Comment: @TheRealJohnDoe I have updated the code in my answer. you need to add payload property

Comment: I got an error in removeEventReducer that events is not defined?

Comment: @TheRealJohnDoe I have updated the reducers code in my answer, please use that

Comment: should I change something in my dispatch function inside the Event component because i updated the code and  it still giving me id is not defined  :D

Comment: @TheRealJohnDoe You need to remove {} around the `id`